# Duplicate console.log output of gun map when using gundb

Tags: gun

Does this function duplicate results as a bug or am I causing this? The output always has 1 or more records duplicated. In this example, Bank of China is always listed twice in output.

```js
gun.get('savings_accounts').map(function (name, ID) {
    console.log( name.name, ID );
}, true)
```

My code:

```js
localStorage.clear();
var gun = Gun();

////////////////////////////////////////////////////// create record
var acc1 = gun.put({
    name: "Bank of America",
    accType: "Savings",
    last4: "4123",
    favorite: true,
    status: true,
    created: "some date created"
    });
var acc2 = gun.put({
    name: "Bank of China",
    accType: "Savings",
    last4: "5123",
    favorite: true,
    status: true,
    created: "some date created"
    });

gun.get('savings_accounts').map(function (name, ID) {
    console.log( name.name, ID );
}, true)
```

Answer (score 6):

*From the author of GunDB, Mark Nadal*

1) `gun.get('savings_accounts').map().val(cb)` is what you want for normal / procedural / easy things.
HOWEVER...

2) gun is actually functional/reactive (FRP), or also known as streaming/event oriented. The data might/will get called multiple times (if you don't use `.val`) because A) in-memory replies, B) your browser's localStorage replies, C) the server will reply, D) server will relay to other browser peers which each might reply with data.
^ that is the "realtime" part of gun.

`.val` only fires once (well per item on the chain, so if you do `map().val(cb)` the `val` will get fired multiple times but only once from each item in the list).

use `.val(cb)` if you are doing procedural things.

Use `.on(cb)` *(which is what `.map(cb)` uses internally. Most API methods internally use `.on`)* if you want to subscribe to realtime updates of the data.
you'll slowly find that the realtime/FRP/event/streaming as being a much cleaner way to write your apps.